# Using filters in Controller instead of in Expression

Tags: angularjs, filter, controller, angular-ui

I am using date filter of 'Angular-UI' (Datepicker) in which I can filter date in dd-mm-yy format. Following is the code:

```
<input id="fromDate" name="fromDate" ng-click="open($event,'fromDate')" data-ng-model="filter.fromDate" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="datepickers.fromDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" />
{{filter.fromDate|date:'dd-mm-yy'}}
```

This is eazy as the datepicker now provides me date in required format. However, similar thing if I try to do in controller, I am unable to achive.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']); 
app.controller = ('myCtrl', function($scope, $filter) { 
$scope.filter.fromDate = ""; 
$scope.reqDate = ""; 
$scope.reqDate = $filter('$scope.filter.fromDate', date:'dd-mm-yy'); 
});
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: `$scope.filter.fromDate` needs to be Date object in order to format it as date, not empty string `$scope.filter.fromDate = ""`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the date filter is not part of Angular-UI. It's part of AngularJS itself.

To get a filter, named 'date', from the code, you use the $filter service, and pass it the name of the filter: `'date'`. It returns the filtering function:

```
var dateFilter = $filter('date');
```

This function takes the input to filter as first argument (i.e. what you put before the `|` in the view), and additional arguments if needed (i.e. what you put after `:` in the view):

```
$scope.reqDate = dateFilter($scope.filter.fromDate, 'dd-MM-yy');
```

The whole thing can of course be done in a single line:

```
$scope.reqDate = $filter('date')($scope.filter.fromDate, 'dd-MM-yy');
```